# Hide StackPanel item --> adjust remaining item positions

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers

(using VS 2010)  I'm new to WPF and am trying to create a TreeViewItem that displays 2 images, then some text.  To do this I'm using StackPanel.  I want the first image to show/hide depending upon changes to model property, so I added a trigger to set its width to 0:

```
 <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="Auto">
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LinkType}" Value="Co">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Image1.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LinkType}" Value="Post">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>

                    <Image Source="/Images/Image2.png"
                        Width="15"
                        Height="15"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="3,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>



            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

This does in fact hide the image, but leaves an empty gap- the remaining items in the stackpanel do not slide to the left to account for the "removal" of the first image.  I also tried triggering to Visibility with same results.

Is there a way I can add/remove, or show/hide, or change width=0, etc, items in StackPanel so that the remaining items readjust their positions accordingly?  Or is there a better container than stackpanel for this?

Comment: +1 Excellent question, well asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you are using a TreeView, the direct "children" of the TreeView are not actually your Image controls - your Image controls are contained within TreeViewItem controls. These are generated automatically and allow the TreeView to handle its children in a more intuitive way (without forcing all controls to implement the properties/functions required of a TreeView child).

It's easy to customize these TeeViewItems. They share the same DataContext as your Images, so you can set the TreeView.ItemContainerStyle like so:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LinkType}" Value="Post">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers> 
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks - it was setting the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` that did the trick. Before I had tried `Hidden`, which was still reserving the whitespace.